# O que significa "com jeito"?

Tags: significado, expressões

O que significa "com jeito", como por exemplo no texto: "**Acho que, com jeito, você teria descoberto a verdade**"?

Pode ser "em jeito certo"?

Comment: "descobrido"? Que texto é esse? O particípio passado de descobrir é descoberto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma definição nas linhas que você sugere poderia ser `do jeito certo` (**em jeito certo* não estaria correto), mas uma melhor ainda seria `com habilidade` ou `com cuidado`.

O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/jeito/) nos dá:

> Com jeito: a) com prudência; prudentemente; b) [fig] com cuidado; cautelosamente.

A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/jeito) tem uma definição compatível:

> **com jeito** com cuidado, convenientemente

Já o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/jeito) lista um significado que nunca vi em pt-BR:

> **com jeito** • Com perfeição.

Comment: Acho que é a definição do Priberam que não é muito feliz. _Com jeito_ significa aqui com cuidado, com habilidade. Por outro lado, uma coisa _sem jeito_ é uma coisa infeliz.

Answer (score 1):

[**"Com jeito"**](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/jeito) definido como "com habilidade", é uma expressão genérica. Dependendo do contexto e da "artimanha" usada, pode implicar comportamentos diversos, reprováveis ou não:

- **com jeitinho** - não tentar arrancar a verdade à força, ou então pedir a ajuda de uma terceira pessoa mais habilidosa, etc.
- **com cuidado ou tato** - conversando cuidadosamente para não pisar nos calos e nem tocar em algum nervo que vá despertar emoções fortes.
- **com habilidade ou dextreza** - perguntando diretamente, fazendo sua inteligência trabalhar a seu favor, demonstrando sinceridade e explicando a necessidade de se saber a verdade. Em suma, convencendo o seu interlocutor a lhe contar a verdade.
- **através de atos ilícitos** - pagando uma propina, chantageando, ameaçando, etc.
- **com astúcia ou malícia** - fingindo ser amigo, ouvindo atrás da porta, usando seu charme pessoal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que 'com jeito' não se fala muito em PT-BR. Aqui se usa muito uma expressão com inúmeros significados, 'jeitinho' (positivos ou negativos). Com jeitinho? 'Jeitinho' pode simbolizar (em meu entendimento) essa 'delicadeza' ao tratar com a/o outra/o.

Nesta frase específica que você coloca, eu entenderia, pelo contexto algo como "com a delicadeza adequada à situação" = com jeito...

Comment: Ouço muito as seguintes expressões aqui no Sudeste: *com jeito* você consegue, vê se *dá um jeitinho* , é sempre *o jeitinho brasileiro*, tenta de novo que *com jeito vai*, *de qualquer jeito*, não, *de jeito maneira*, não vou aceitar *de jeito nenhum*, você *não tem jeito* mesmo, que *falta de jeito* pra fazer as coisas, etc.

Comment: Na realidade 'de jeito maneira' é expressão do nordeste (de origem), as demais eu também ouvia (quando morava aí). Só que a construção como foi feita tá muito 'elíptica' pra ser pt-br... "acho que (se você tivesse feito/falado) com jeito, teria descoberto a verdade", pelo menos me parece...